# jQuery Smart Wizard v4 Step Validaton using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, smart-wizard

Here, I am using jQuery Smart Wizard v4 to my form, There are three steps and each step have some input fields. My question is, just I need to validate each field before going to the next step.

HTML from my Form is Something similar to this:

```
<form class="regform" action="" method="post" id="addNew_user">
  <div id="Regwizard">
    <ul>
      <li class="wizard-progressbar"></li>
      <li><a href="#step-1">Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-2">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-3">Permissions</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="px-2 py-2">
      <div id="step-1">
        <h4>Enter the following user information</h4> 
        
        <div id="form-step-0">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="step-2">
        <h4>Enter the following login information</h4> 
      
        <div id="form-step-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="step-3" class="pt-0">
        <h4>Check the boxes below to access modules.</h4> 

        <div id="form-step-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="1" /> Module Name
            <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="2" /> Module Name
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is how I tried it in jQuery:

```
$('#userRegwizard').smartWizard({
  theme: 'circles',
  useURLhash: false,
  showStepURLhash: false,
  autoAdjustHeight: true,
  transitionSpeed: 150,
  toolbarSettings: {
    toolbarPosition: 'bottom', 
    toolbarButtonPosition: 'right',
    showNextButton: false,
    showPreviousButton: false, 
    toolbarExtraButtons: [
      $('<div class="loader mr-3 d-none"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin text-blue fa-2x"></i></div>'),
      $('<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary sw-btn-prev radius-l-1 mr-2px"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left mr-15"></i> Previous</button>'),
      $('<button class="btn btn-outline-primary sw-btn-next sw-btn-hide radius-r-1">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right mr-15"></i></button>'),
      $('<button class="btn btn-green sw-btn-finish radius-r-1 regThisUser"><i class="fa fa-check mr-15"></i> Submit</button>')
    ]
  }
}) 

.on("showStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {

})

$('#addNew_user').validate({
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorClass: 'form-text form-error text-danger-m2',
  focusInvalid: false,
  ignore:  "",
  rules: {
    email: {
      email: true
    },          
    username: {
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },
    password_conform: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      equalTo: "#password"
    }
  }
}) 

$('#userRegwizard').on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
  var elmForm = $("#form-step-" + stepNumber);
  if (stepDirection == 'forward' && elmForm) {
    if ($('#addNew_user').valid()) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
  }
  //return true;
})
```

But this `js` code not works for me. That mean I can't go to next step, But its going to next step if I remove validation code from `leaveStep` method. Can somebody help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ignore:  "",
```

Why did you set `ignore` to "nothing"?  This means the plugin will ignore nothing and validate everything.

So when you call `.valid()` it's validating every single input on your form, even the empty ones in other steps you cannot see... that's why you are stuck.

Remove the `ignore` option entirely to restore the default behavior of ignoring hidden inputs and only validating what is being shown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... let me check it