# jQuery Smart Wizard - cancel move to next step if validation fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, smart-wizard

I am using the jQuery SmartWizard for one of my projects. I have validations in place via the jQuery Validation plugin which appear to be working. The issue is that I want SmartWizard to stop users from navigating to the next step if validation for the current step failed.

The code below seems to work since I can see the `Form on step X is invalid` console log entry, but the following `return false`, which supposedly should stop the user from navigating to the next step, seems to be ignored even though validation clearly failed.

I alternatively tried binding the function to a `click` event for the `sw-btn-next` button, which is the button thats clicked to proceed to the next step, but this does not seem to work either.

jQuery 3.2.1 // Bootstrap 3.3.7 // SmartWizard 5.1.1 (latest) // jQuery Validation 1.19.3 (latest)

**jQuery Validation**

```
// set validation rules for entire form
$('#addNewUser').validate({
    debug: true,
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'form-text form-error text-red',
    focusInvalid: false,
    rules: {
        'first_name': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        'last_name': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
        },
        'password': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 25
        },
        'password_repeat': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 25,
            equalTo: '#password'
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'first_name': 'Please enter a valid first name'
    }
});
```

**SmartWizard**

```
// ###################################
// # jQuery SmartWizard  plugin
// ###################################
$('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
    selected: 0,        // Initial selected step, 0 = first step
    theme: 'default'   // theme for the wizard, related css need to include for other than default theme

    // when changing steps...
}).on("stepContent", function(e, anchorObject, stepIndex, stepDirection) {

    // check if current step is Step 5 and enable submit button
    $('#newUserSubmit').prop('disabled', stepIndex !== 4);
    console.log('Navigated to stepIndex ' + stepIndex + ' moving in stepDirection ' + stepDirection);

    // check form validation
    var elmForm = $('#form-step-' + stepIndex);
    if (stepDirection == 'forward' && elmForm) {
        if ($('#addNewUser').valid()) {
            console.log('Form on Step ' + stepIndex + ' is valid');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('Form on Step ' + stepIndex + ' is invalid');
            return false;
        }
    }

});

// when clicking NEXT button...
$('.sw-btn-next').click(function() {
    console.log('Next button clicked.')
});
```

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work.  By default, the Validate plugin ignores the parts that are hidden and only validates the step that is show.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/68561398/594235  Otherwise, I would break it up into separate forms.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/17748545/594235

Comment: I did try that just now, breaking up one long form into 1 form per step, but `.validate` doesnt seem to work for multiple fields. The linked post is from 8+ years ago and most likely that way of calling validation is not supported anymore.

Comment: The core of the plugin works the same today as it did 8 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of trial and error, I finally fixed the issue by moving the validation check from SmartWizard's `stepContent` event to the `leaveStep` event. Please note that the often referenced `$('.sw-btn-next').click(function()` does not work either, it has to be `leaveStep`.

```
// ###################################
// # jQuery SmartWizard  plugin
// ###################################
$('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
    selected: 0, // Initial selected step, 0 = first step
    theme: 'default', // theme for the wizard, related css need to include for other than default theme
    justified: true, // Nav menu justification. true/false
    darkMode: false, // Enable/disable Dark Mode if the theme supports. true/false
    autoAdjustHeight: true, // Automatically adjust content height
    cycleSteps: false, // Allows to cycle the navigation of steps
    backButtonSupport: true, // Enable the back button support
    enableURLhash: false, // Enable selection of the step based on url hash
    // onFinish: onFinishCallback,
    // onCancel: onCancelCallback,
    transition: {
        animation: 'fade', // Effect on navigation, none/fade/slide-horizontal/slide-vertical/slide-swing
        speed: '400', // Transion animation speed
        easing: '' // Transition animation easing. Not supported without a jQuery easing plugin
    },
    toolbarSettings: {
        toolbarPosition: 'bottom', // none, top, bottom, both
        toolbarButtonPosition: 'center', // left, right, center
        showNextButton: true, // show/hide a Next button
        showPreviousButton: true, // show/hide a Previous button
        toolbarExtraButtons: [ // Extra buttons to show on toolbar, array of jQuery input/buttons elements
            $('<button id="newUserSubmit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary-bordered" disabled><i class="fa fa-check mr-15"></i> Submit</button>')
        ]
    },
    anchorSettings: {
        anchorClickable: false, // Enable/Disable anchor navigation
        enableAllAnchors: false, // Activates all anchors clickable all times
        markDoneStep: false, // Add done state on navigation
        markAllPreviousStepsAsDone: true, // When a step selected by url hash, all previous steps are marked done
        removeDoneStepOnNavigateBack: false, // While navigate back done step after active step will be cleared
        enableAnchorOnDoneStep: true // Enable/Disable the done steps navigation
    },
    keyboardSettings: {
        keyNavigation: false, // Enable/Disable keyboard navigation(left and right keys are used if enabled)
        keyLeft: [37], // Left key code
        keyRight: [39] // Right key code
    },
    lang: { // Language variables for button
        next: 'Next >',
        previous: '< Previous'
    },
    // disabledSteps: [],                       // Array Steps disabled
    // errorSteps: [],                          // Highlight step with errors
    // hiddenSteps: []                          // Hidden steps

    // when changing steps...
}).on("stepContent", function(e, anchorObject, stepIndex, stepDirection) {
    // on step 1, focus on First Name input field
    if (stepIndex == 1) {
        $("#first_name").focus();
    }

    // check if current step is stepIndex 4 and enable submit button
    if (stepIndex == 4) {
        // enable form submit button on last step
        $('#newUserSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
        console.log('StepIndex is 4, enabling submit button');
    } else {
        // disable form submit button on all other steps
        $('#newUserSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
        console.log('StepIndex is not 4, disabling submit button');
    }
});

// Initialize the leaveStep event
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepIndex, nextStepIndex, stepDirection) {
    // navigate to next step
    console.log('Navigated to stepIndex ' + stepIndex + ' moving in stepDirection ' + stepDirection);

    // check if current form step is valid
    var elmForm = $('#form-step-' + stepIndex);
    if (stepDirection == 'forward' && elmForm) {
        if ($('#addNewUser').valid()) {
            console.log('Form on Step ' + stepIndex + ' is valid');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('Form on Step ' + stepIndex + ' is invalid');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Above code works provides a working SmartWizard step-by-step wizard with jQuery Validation for each step by calling validation for the entire `form` when the user navigates away from the current step. Additionally, the script places an extra `Submit` button to the wizard which is automatically disable unless the user has reached the final step of the wizard.

There is surprisingly little documentation for this particular use-case, I hope this helps anyone else who experiences issues with SmartWizard & jQuery Validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by customizing the onLeaveStep callback.
This is the piece of code I am currently using to validate each step separately :

```
$('#smartwizard').on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, nextStepNumber, stepDirection) {

var arrStep = Array(stepNumber.toString())
var elmForm = $("#step-" + stepNumber);

//Loop thru all input fields of the current "partial" form and validate them
var inputs = elmForm.find("input");

if(stepDirection==='forward') {
    //Validate the current form fields
    for (const element of inputs) {
        valid = $('#myForm').validate().element(element);

        if (!valid) {
            return false; //Don't go next step
        }
    }
}
})
```